# Why am I getting a "destination path '.' already exists" error when trying clone from my webfaction server?

Tags: git, webfaction

I'm trying to use `git clone` to download the codes from my webfaction server

```
$ cd ../webapps/nameofwebapp/
$ git clone git@github.com:github-username/github-repo.git ./
```

AND there is error :

```
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

I use ls and there are something under the `nameofwebapp`

```
auth  git.cgi  gitweb.cgi  repos  static
```

I want to ask where to use `git clone` 
Do I need to make a new directory??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
git clone git@github.com:github-username/github-repo.git
```

That will create a new folder `github-repo` in `../webapps/nameofwebapp/`.

In your case:

```
cd ../webapps/nameofwebapp/
git clone git@github.com:github-username/github-repo.git -b develop ./
```

If you already did the clone:

```
cd github-repo
git checkout -b develop origin/develop
```

Comment: it works but seems it clone the wrong branch.there are tow branches on git.master and develop.and I want to clone develop

Comment: now my git branch only have "master".I want to delete it and retry your "git clone git@github.com:github-username/github-repo.git -b develop ./"  can you teach me how to remove the github-repo directory

Comment: @user2492364 you can remove the folder. But I have fixed the checkout command. Give it a try.

Comment: @user2492364 yes, the `clone` command clones *all* branches in the `origin` namespace. You just need to create the one you need from one of those `origin/xxx` branches.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a same name git project directory in current path, git clone command will create a new directory and will crash if there is a same name directory.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was related to SSH keys. When I set the key, it worked fine.